# All possible combinations of two arrays in access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am comparing readings in six different manuscripts (1,2,3,4,5,6) and noting which manuscripts align with which. I use the following code to set up the left side of the equation with one array of all possible agreements:

```
Dim sBin(64) As String, Counter0 As Byte
For Counter0 = 0 To 63
sBin(Counter0) = IIf(Counter0 And (2 ^ 5), "1", "") _
& IIf(Counter0 And (2 ^ 4), "2", "") & IIf(Counter0 And (2 ^ 3), "3", "") _
& IIf(Counter0 And (2 ^ 2), "4", "") & IIf(Counter0 And (2 ^ 1), "5", "") _
& IIf(Counter0 And (2 ^ 0), "6", "")
Next Counter0
```

This results in the following array:
"",6,5,56,4,46,45,456,...123456

Taking those results as the array on the left side of the equation A() <> B(), what code in Access VBA would yield all possible combinations in the right side of the equation? For example, several possible combinations are:
A(6) <> B(25), A(456) <> B(3), A(1) <> B(23456), A(1) <> B(6)

Comment: First there is no `IIF()` in VBA but in Access SQL dialect. Second, you do not use any of the Access object model, so can safely say and tag this as a general VBA question. Finally, if you provide actual or mock data of manuscripts and desired recordset results, you might be able to run a cross join SQL query which list all possibilities of a given set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difficulty is selecting and permuting the manuscripts for the right side of each equation based on which manuscripts are in the left side of the equation, since no manuscript can disagree with itself. Here is a solution that works, and is scalable. With a total of seven manuscripts, it yields 728 unique combinations.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ms(6) As String
Dim LAlign(64) As String, LAlignA(6) As String, RAlign(64) As String, RAlignA(6) As String
Dim LARA(727) As String
Dim i0 As Integer, i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer

Private Sub Command0_Click()
For i0 = 0 To 6 'Set manuscript descriptors
    Ms(i0) = i0
Next i0
i3 = 0 'Start count of all completed alignments
'Set Left side of equations
For i0 = 0 To 62 'These numbers equal (2^n)-1 possibilities that eliminate the zero set
    LAlign(i0) = ""
    For i1 = 0 To 6
        If i0 And (2 ^ i1) Then LAlign(i0) = LAlign(i0) & Ms(i1 + 1)
    Next i1
'Set right side of equations for each left side
    For i1 = 0 To 5 'Clear each component of alignments and concatenated alignments
        RAlignA(i1) = ""
    Next i1
        RAlign(i0) = ""
    i2 = 0
    For i1 = 0 To 5 'Set each component of alignments and concatenate alignments
        If InStr(LAlign(i0), Ms(i1 + 1)) = 0 Then
            If Ms(i1 + 1) <> "0" Then RAlignA(i2) = Ms(i1 + 1): RAlign(i0) = RAlign(i0) & RAlignA(i2) Else RAlignA(i2) = ""
            i2 = i2 + 1
        End If
    Next i1
    For i1 = 0 To Choose(Len(RAlign(i0)), 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63) 'Len(RAlign(i0)) starts with 1; these numbers equal (2^n) possibilities that do not eliminate the zero set
        RAlign(i1) = ""
        For i2 = 0 To 5 'Set each Right Alignment
            If i1 And (2 ^ i2) Then RAlign(i1) = RAlign(i1) Else RAlign(i1) = RAlign(i1) & RAlignA(i2)
        Next i2
        If RAlign(i1) <> "" Then 'Combine Left Alignment and Right Alignment
            LARA(i3) = Ms(0) & LAlign(i0) & " <> " & RAlign(i1) 'Regular combinations
            Else
            LARA(i3) = Ms(0) & LAlign(i0) & " <> each other ms " 'Unique readings
        End If
        Debug.Print LARA(i3)
        i3 = i3 + 1
    Next i1
Next i0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop within a loop

```
Dim counterOuter As Byte
Dim counterInner As Byte

For counterOuter = 0 To 63
   For counterInner = counterOuter+1 To 63
       'Do here your operation
       'A(counterOuter) <> B(counterInner)  
   Next counterInner
Next counterOuter
```

I assume you do not want to have repeated combinations. There should be 2080 combinations.